# How to run Spark Java samples using jar

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am trying to run Spark Java samples using jar. For `sparkPi` sample alone command is available. How to run other Java samples like `HdfsLR`, `Logquery`, `Pagerank`, `Statustrackerdemo`, `javaTC` in spark using jar.

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation](https://github.com/mudrutom/spark-examples) ?

Comment: yes, But by using this jar file how to execute these samples using spark command ?

Comment: you should use spark submit command

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of submitting jars to spark cluster is through the following command if running in local mode :

spark-submit  --class "package.class Name" --master local[2] "path_to_your_jar_file"

If there is no package name ignore package & just give class name in the above command.

Note if spark home is not set you should go to spark/bin directory & execute the above command there